# Disabled controls from FormGroup (part of form custom form control) are excluded by .getRawValue() in parent

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Having a component that implements `ControlValueAccessor`, with internal `FormGroup` to maintain the state of custom form control. When any field, that's part of that `FormGroup` is disabled, the field isn't visible when calling `.getRawValue()` method in parent form .

By specification, `.getRawValue()` should return the raw object, including disabled fields.

I've checked the code of `.getRawValue()` and here's what I found:

```
 getRawValue(): any {
    return this._reduceChildren(
        {}, (acc: {[k: string]: AbstractControl}, control: AbstractControl, name: string) => {
          acc[name] = control instanceof FormControl ? control.value : (<any>control).getRawValue();
          return acc;
        });
  }
```

So, basically, when form control is instance of `FormControl` (that's the case when using custom form controls, correct?), it retrieves `.value` instead of `.getRawValue()` and that's why the disabled controls of nested form are **not included** in the final object.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-reactive-form-jjgkef)

Steps to reproduce:

1) Click on "Disable year" button on any of three custom form controls displayed in the UI.

2) Examine the output below => `.getRawValue()` and `.value` responses are identical.

Do you have any idea how I can overcome this? I'm looking for a way to retrieve the disabled controls as well in the parent form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kav, in your custom form control you has

```
  registerOnChange(fn: (v: any) => void) {
        this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
    }
```

so, your component return the "value" of formGroup. As a control is disabled, the value not return this field. You can change your customControl to return the rawValue of the formGroup, for this you need create a onChangeFunction, and in a ngOnInit subscribe to changes and send the rawValues. As we subscribe it's good unsubscribe using a takeWhile and a variable

```
export class DetailsFields implements ControlValueAccessor,OnInit,OnDestroy {
    ...
    onChange: (v:any) => void = () => {}; //<--define a function
    isAlive:boolean=true; //<--use to unsubscribe, see below

    registerOnChange(fn: (v: any) => void) {
      this.onChange = fn; //<--equal to function
    }

    //In ngOnInit
    ngOnInit()
    {
      this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(takeWhile(()=>this.isAlive))
        .subscribe(v=>{
        //return this.formGroup.getRawValue()
        this.onChange(this.formGroup.getRawValue())
      })
    }
    //In ngOnDestroy
    ngOnDestroy() {  //make isAlive=False to unsubscribe
      this.isAlive=false;
    }
```

But in this case, you received the year always is enabled or not

There're another aproach, that is not have a custom form control, just a component to manage the make,year and color. For this, the first is change your app-component and create the form like another form with a formArray.

```
<div id="cars" [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="cars">
  <div *ngFor="let car of form.get('cars').controls; let i = index;" 
   [formGroupName]="i">
    <app-details-fields [formGroup]="form.get('cars').at(i)" ></app-details-fields>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See that in a formArray we iterate over form.get('cars').controls and we need put a [formGroupName]="i". In the component simply pass as input [formGroup] form.get('cars').at(i)

Of course, you need change your function "createCars" to return a formGroup. not a formControl that return an object type {make:..,color:..,year}

```
createCar(car: any) {  //return a formGroup,not a formControl
    return this.builder.group({
      make: car.make,
      color: car.color,
      year: car.year
    });
  }
```

Well, the details-fields becomes easer:

details-fields.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-details-fields',
  templateUrl: './details-fields.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details-fields.component.css']  ,
})

export class DetailsFields {
   @Input() formGroup:FormGroup

   disableYear() {
      this.formGroup.get('year').disable();
    }

    enableYear() {
      this.formGroup.get('year').enable();
    }
}
```

details-fields.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div class="car-wrap">
      <div>
          <p class="title">This car is a {{formGroup.get('make').value}}</p>
      <div>
        <input type="text" formControlName="make">
        <input type="number" formControlName="year">
        <input type="text" formControlName="color">
      </div>
      <div>
        <button style="margin-top: 3px;" (click)="enableYear()">Enable year</button>
        <button style="margin-top: 3px;" (click)="disableYear()">Disable year</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You rock! I've decided to go with the first approach, because I created a really simple demo to show what the issue is. In reality, my custom control have much more responsibilities, etc. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simply do that:

```
registerOnChange(fn: (v: any) => void) {
    this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(map(_ => this.formGroup.getRawValue())).subscribe(fn);
}
```