# Angular: Make Form Values ReadOnly Greyed Out And Data Getter Valid with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular10

Is there anyway to make a form greyed out readonly,  While making the form values acquirable?

[image]

1/This will not work `control.disable()` in Typescript, as I cannot acquire the values of Id, Name, Description afterwards.

```
this.roleForm = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl(this.singleRole?.id),
  name: new FormControl(this.singleRole?.name),
  createDate: new FormControl(this.singleRole?.createDate),
  status: new FormControl(this.singleRole?.status)
});

this.roleForm.controls['id'].disable();
this.roleForm.controls['name'].disable();
this.roleForm.controls['createDate'].disable();
```

I will not see values for three above

```
console.log(this.roleForm.value)
```

2/ Using only Fieldset will make the values greyed out AND acquirable.
*I am trying to control this functionality with Typescript, and Not HTML.

```
  <fieldset class="data-form" [disabled]="true">
    <mat-form-field class="row" appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Id</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="id" [value] = "singleRole.id" >
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="row" appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="name" [value] = "singleRole.name" >
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="row" appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Created Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="createDate" [value] = "singleRole.createDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'" >
    </mat-form-field>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Did you try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167970/disabled-controls-from-formgroup-part-of-form-custom-form-control-are-excluded)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be able to get the values of disabled form control with `formgroup.value`.
But you can try `formGroup.rawValue` which is supposed to get the values of disabled controls too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with  [formControl]="id" which is easily able to get values from Input tag.